# Puppeteer Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, puppeteer, nodes

```js
await products?.map(async ilan => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            const email = "";
            const password = "";
            const title = ilan.title;
            const location = ilan.Country[random].country;
            const categories = ilan.category;
            const link = ilan.link;
            const description = ilan.description;
            const manufacturer = ilan.manufacturer;
            const model = ilan.model;
            const year = ilan.year;
            console.log('title', title)
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                // devtools: true
                // defaultViewport: null,
                // headless: true,
                // executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
                // args: ['--no-sandbox'],
            });
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto('');

            // await page.screenshot({ path: 'example.png' });
            // ! Email
            async function input(focus, deger) {
                await page.focus(focus)
                await page.keyboard.type(deger)
            }
            await input('#user_email', email)
            await input('#user_password', password)
            // ! Submit
            await page.click('input[type="submit"]')
            await page.waitForTimeout(10000)
            // ! Title
            await input('input[id="api_listing_title"]', title)
            // ! Location
            await input('input[id="api_listing_location"]', location)
            // ! Categories
            await input('input[type="search"]', categories)
            await page.click('li[role="option"]')
            // ! Youtube Link
            await input('input[id="youtube_link"]', link)
            // ! Description
            await input('textarea[name="api_listing[description]"]', description)
            // ! Manufacturer 
            await input('input[name="api_listing[manufacturer]"]', manufacturer)
            await input('input[name="api_listing[model]"]', model)
            await input('input[name="api_listing[year]"]', year)
            await page.select('#api_listing_condition', 'new')
            // ! Resim
            const inputUploadHandle = await page.$('input[type=file]');
            ilan.images?.map(async image => {
                await inputUploadHandle.uploadFile(image.path)
            })
            await page.waitForTimeout(10000)
            await page.click('input[name="commit"]')
            await page.waitForTimeout(15000)

            await browser.close();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(" error", error)
            res.json({ message: 'error' })
        }
    })(ilan);
})
```

```
(node:20436) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:20436) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20436) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGTERM listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20436) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I get this error when the program runs

Comment: You want to move browser.close() outside of the try block or else they won't always get closed.

Comment: Try to put `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});` and `await browser.close();` out of `await products?.map()` loop and reuse the same browser in the loop. It will be faster and will use less resources.

Comment: all right, it's solved

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @pguardiario worked for me too.

Suggestion:

```js
try {
  ...
} catch (...) {
  ...
} finally {
  await browser.close();
}
```